# Device cannot login

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple user model

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
       # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
       # :token_authenticatable,
       # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
       devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,:confirmable, :validatable
       include BCrypt

  #attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

  has_many :deals
  has_many :charges
  has_one :menu
  has_many :vouchers
  has_one :authentication
  has_many :restaurant_tags
  has_many :restaurant_hours

  #validates :login, uniqueness: true
  #validates :login, presence: true
  validates :password, presence: { on: :create }
  validates :password, confirmation: true
  #validates :login, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :on     => :create, message: "must be a valid email address."}
  validates :role, inclusion: { in: ["admin", "client", "restaurant"] }

  #before_save :encrypt_password

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
     self.salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.crypted_password = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
    end
  end

   def self.authenticate(login, password)
    user = find_by_login(login)
    if user && user.crypted_password == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def restaurant?
    role == "restaurant"
  end

  def client?
    role == "client"
  end

  def admin?
    role == "admin"
  end

end
```

and devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = "please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com"
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.authentication_keys = [ :email, :login]
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email, login]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email, login ]
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10
  config.reconfirmable = true
  config.password_length = 6..128
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
end
```

I can sign up successfully and after confirmation I can see I am logged in but when I sign out and then try to login I am face error Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms. I have already spent whole day on this please help me out Thanks

Comment: I see you have commented out the `before_save :encrypt_password` line, so are you calling that method from somewhere else? If not, I imagine the `authenticate` method would indeed fail since the original password was not encrypted with the `BCrypt` engine (and therefore the encrypted passwords would not match). Is that possible?

Comment: You are right but Devise encrypt password automatically we need not to encrypt password.

Comment: remove or comment your custom authentication from everywhere , with devise u don't need to do that....and remove the "include bcrypt" also..

Comment: i don't know why you encrypt the password be yourself? that's all done by devise?

Comment: @devanand I have disable this which means i am not calling this method #before_save :encrypt_password

Comment: yes i've seen :) remove the authenticate method as well. this is also be done by devise afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem the devise was checking the login field for authenticate while I was using email in my views i just updated

```
 config.authentication_keys = [:email]
 config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]
 config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]
```

and this solve my problem thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

please update this method

```
def self.authenticate(login, password)
        user = self.find_by_login(login)
        if user && user.crypted_password == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.salt)
          user
        else
          nil
        end
      end
```